# I am having trouble setting up a website implemented with a simple database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, sqlite

this is my first question on here, so please be patient with me.  :)
So, I have spent hours trying to fix this problem but haven't found a solution.
The problem is pretty simple:

I am using the Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate 90-day-trial and ASP.Net Framework 4.5 and C# to create a simple web site in which a user can create an account, meaning that their account data would need to be saved to a database.

The database tool I am using is SQLite, because I read this is a great tool to use for small databases.

So, my application runs fine until I actually enter in a test-user's information and click on my "Create Account!" button.  At this point my application gives me the following error:

### ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

> Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS
>   Express\databaseFile.db3' is denied.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the
>   path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\databaseFile.db3' is denied.
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request
>   identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically
>   {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and
>   the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if
>   the application is not impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity will be
>   the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File
>   Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add"
>   to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account,
>   and check the boxes for the desired access.

**Source Error:**

> Line 28:                           )"; Line 29:  Line 30:
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("databaseFile.db3");
>   // Create the file which will be hosting our database Line 31:
>   using (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection con = new
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("data source=databaseFile.db3"))
>   Line 32:             {
>
> Source File: c:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\WebDataBase\WebDataBase\SignUpForm.aspx.cs    Line: 30
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\IIS Express\databaseFile.db3' is denied.]
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   +217    System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share,
>   Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs,
>   String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean
>   checkHost) +1305    System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode
>   mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize) +63
>   System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(String
>   databaseFileName) +38    WebDataBase.SignUpForm.AddNewUser(String pw)
>   in c:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\WebDataBase\WebDataBase\SignUpForm.aspx.cs:30
>   WebDataBase.SignUpForm.Button_CREATE_ACCOUNT_Click1(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\WebDataBase\WebDataBase\SignUpForm.aspx.cs:71
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9653178
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +103
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +35    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1724

### ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Okay, so, I read that to fix this problem all I have to do is simply grant access to the database file, but I can't do this because the database file doesn't exist yet.

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks!   :D

Oh, here is my code if you need that:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace WebDataBase
{
    public partial class SignUpForm : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void AddNewUser(string pw)
        {
            string email = TextBox_EMAIL.Text;
            string username = TextBox_USERNAME.Text;

            string createTableQuery = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [UserData] (
                          [ID] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                          [Email] NVARCHAR(30)  NULL,
                          [Username] NVARCHAR(12)  NULL,
                          [Password] NVARCHAR(12) NULL
                          )";

            System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("databaseFile.db3");        // Create the file which will be hosting our database
            using (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection con = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("data source=databaseFile.db3"))
            {
                using (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand com = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand(con))
                {
                    con.Open();                             // Open the connection to the database

                    com.CommandText = createTableQuery;     // Set CommandText to our query that will create the table
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();                  // Execute the query

                    com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO UserData (ID,Email,Username,Password) Values ('" + email + "','" + username + "','" + pw + "')";     // Add the first entry into our database 
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();      // Execute the query
                    //com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO UserData (ID,Email,Username,Password) Values ('key two','value value')";   // Add another entry into our database 
                    // com.ExecuteNonQuery();      // Execute the query

                    com.CommandText = "Select * FROM UserData";      // Select all rows from our database table

                    using (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            string row = (reader["ID"] + " : " + reader["Email"] + " : " +
                                reader["Username"] + " : " + reader["Password"]);     // Display the value of the key and value column for every row
                            Label1.Text = row;
                        }
                    }
                    con.Close();        // Close the connection to the database
                }
            }

        }

        protected void Button_CREATE_ACCOUNT_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = "";
            string pw = TextBox_PASSWORD.Text;
            string confirmedPw = TextBox_CONFIRM_PASSWORD.Text;

            // Check if "password" and "confirm password" values are the same
            if (pw.Equals(confirmedPw, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                AddNewUser(pw);
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "Passwords are not matching.  Please make sure they are matching.";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running Visual Studio as an Administrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give you application rights on the `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\` folder itself (which I would probably not recommend) or else use a different folder actually inside the project folder (looks like it's `c:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebDataBase\WebDataBase` in your case) instead, which would be my recommendation.